# Upload Attachment to SP List but Files either are empty or not able to open

Tags: file-upload, attachments, angularjs

I am trying to upload an attachment to my Sharepoint list and the upload goes well with a 200 message, however when I go to my list and try to open it, if it is a pdf will open an empty file with the same number of pages of the original file but no content and if it's a docx it won't open, it gives an error message.
My code  to upload is:

```
function upload() {
        var file;
        var count = 0;
        // $('input[type=file]').val(function (e) {
        file = $("#attachment-file")[0].files[0];
        // file = e.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var getFileBuffer = function (file) {

            var deferred = $.Deferred();


            reader.onload = function (e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
            }

            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

            return deferred.promise();
        };

        getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
            timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
            var binary = "";
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            var i = bytes.byteLength;
            while (i--) {
                binary = String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]) + binary;
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('RoutingForm')/Items("+Identification+")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                    data: binary,
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "content-length": binary.byteLength
                    }
                })

                .then(function (success) {
                    count++;
                    // $scope.attachments.push({ name: file.name, link: mainPage + "/Lists/OnBoarding/Attachments/" + Id + "/" + file.name })
                    alert("You have attached the file succesfully!");
                    return;
                },
                function (error) {
                    count++;
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("An error has occured with the attachment. No file has been attached.");
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to modify the file buffer in

```
getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
}
```

block you use below code and try

```
getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
        timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
        var binary = "";
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var content = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray();
```

And in

```
$http({
                method: "POST",
                url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('RoutingForm')/Items("+Identification+")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                data: buffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "content-length": buffer.byteLength
                }
            })
```

Comment: Hi @Sunil! thanks for your input but it still doesn't work.. I also didn't understand what the content variable is doing that if it is not doing anything. Did you mean to use it somewhere else? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes you can skip it, try to processData: false, in ajax call.

Comment: I tried :( it did not work.